# String as calculation in php

Tags: php

I've got field in my database which contain strings like `21;48;33;22;31`. Then I'd like to convert it to mathematical calculation `21+48+33+22+31`.

```
$points = "21;48;33;22;31";
$points = str_replace(";","+",$points );
$points = preg_replace('/[^0-9\+\-\*\/\s]+/', '', $points);
echo $points;
```

But that simply does not work. I've got the same string "21+48+33+22+31" instead of the sum.

Comment: Split up the string by using explode, and then calculate the sum: `array_sum(explode(';', $points));`

Comment: That's because you never **calculate** it...

Answer (score 8):

```
$points = "21;48;33;22;31";
$points = explode(';',$points );
$points = array_sum($points);
echo $points;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$points = "21;48;33;22;31";
$arr = explode(";", $points);
$points = 0;
foreach($arr as $key => $rows){
    $points += $rows[$key];
}
echo $points;
```

Try above code it will give you proper result.

or you can try it also:

```
$points = "21;48;33;22;31";
$arr = explode(";", $points);
echo $points = array_sum($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to [explode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php) the string.

Then you can iterate with foreach over the resulting array and calculate them.

```
$points = "21;48;33;22;31";
$points = explode(";", $points);
$calc = 0;

forearch($points as $point) {
    $calc += $point;
}
```

Or your can use [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-sum.php):

```
$points = "21;48;33;22;31";
$points = explode(";", $points);
$calc = array_sum($points);
```

Something like that. Perhaps there are some shorter ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "21;48;33;22;31";

$string = explode(";" , "21;48;33;22;31");


$point = 0;
foreach($string as $num)
{       // by using (int) you can convert string to int.
    $point = (int)$num + $point;

}

print($point);
// output 
155
```

Answer (score 0):

explode it then loop for sum...

```
 <?php
        $total = 0; // for getting the total
        $points = "21;48;33;22;31";
        $points = explode(';',$points);
     for($i=0;$i<count($points);$i++){
        $total+= $points[$i];
    }
    echo $total;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
eval('$sum = ' . str_replace(';','+','21;48;33;22;31').';');
echo $sum;
```